# Hive service fails with derby connection exception

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to set up Hadoop 2.7.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.
I have done the Hadoop single-node cluster; I'm now trying Hive with Derby for metadata.

I believe that I've supplied appropriate permissions on the localhost port in java.policy.  I have Hadoop Services started.
However, when I try to run Hive $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive, it fails with following exception trace.
Any help is appreciated.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-2.0.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-2.0.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3080)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1548)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:361)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:483)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:296)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:133)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:420)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:821)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:338)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:217)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:516)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:547)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3080)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 72 more
------

NestedThrowables:
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:361)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:483)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:296)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 72 more
```

Comment: Clarified the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Your ubuntu server is refusing connections on port 1527.  Either the derby server isn't running or you have a firewall rule blocking the connections.  Run a lsof -i TCP:1527 to see if a process is running on the port.  You can also try telneting to the port with telnet localhost 1527.

If you see a process on the port then the connection is probably blocked by a firewall rule or you have a stale process holding open the port.  You can kill the PID and try restarting hive.

Start by debugging why the Derby server isn't starting by looking at the derby / hive server logs.  These type of conditions are usually caused by permission issues on linux file paths or logs etc.

You may want to do some research on using mysql for your hive metadata if you plan on using this for more than a sandbox environment.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I too have been thinking of using mysql for hive metadata